# SQL query to update value in a row with value from another row in a different column in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
RID|Response|CV1|CV2|SR1|PF1|FD1|
====================================
1 |feedback | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
2 |comment_ | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
3 |2ice wkly| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
4 |CV1|table| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
5 |CV2|frame| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
6 |Poor     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

I want to update all 1 values with the corresponding response value and all response values with the pipe(`|`). I want to replace the value with the part after the bar so my resulting table appears as follows:

```
RID|Response | CV1 | CV2 | SR1|   PF1   |   FD1  |
==================================================
1  |feedback |  0  |  0  |  0 |    0    |feedback|
2  |comment_ |  0  |  0  |  0 |    0    |comment_|
3  |2ice wkly|  0  |  0  |  0 |2ice wkly|   0    |
4  |CV1|table|table|  0  |  0 |    0    |   0    |
5  |CV2|frame|  0  |frame|  0 |    0    |   0    | 
6  |Poor     |  0  |  0  |Poor|    0    |   0    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Update statement -

```
UPDATE tblname SET CV1 = CASE CV1 WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Response,CHARINDEX('|',Response)+1,LEN(Response)) ELSE CV1 END,
                   CV2 = CASE CV2 WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Response,CHARINDEX('|',Response)+1,LEN(Response)) ELSE CV2 END,
                   SR1 = CASE SR1 WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Response,CHARINDEX('|',Response)+1,LEN(Response))ELSE SR1 END,
                   PF1 = CASE PF1 WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Response,CHARINDEX('|',Response)+1,LEN(Response)) ELSE PF1 END,
                   FD1 = CASE FD1 WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Response,CHARINDEX('|',Response)+1,LEN(Response)) ELSE FD1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fields aren't already VARCHAR/NVARCHAR, alter the table so that they are.

Otherwise, just update the table like this:

```
UPDATE tblName
SET [CV1] = CASE [CV1] WHEN '1' THEN RIGHT([Response], LEN([Response]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Response])) ELSE '0' END
  , [CV2] = CASE [CV2] WHEN '1' THEN RIGHT([Response], LEN([Response]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Response])) ELSE '0' END
  , [SR1] = CASE [SR1] WHEN '1' THEN RIGHT([Response], LEN([Response]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Response])) ELSE '0' END
  , [PF1] = CASE [PF1] WHEN '1' THEN RIGHT([Response], LEN([Response]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Response])) ELSE '0' END
  , [FD1] = CASE [FD1] WHEN '1' THEN RIGHT([Response], LEN([Response]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Response])) ELSE '0' END
```